# In Angular, check value if equivalent to one of array value before assigning to object property

Tags: angular, typescript

I have object instance of class 'CheckBoxQuestion'. I need to assign values to its properties. there is property call option[] and here I am assembling key values for  type checklist. Now my issue here is need to compare if item.preDefineAnswerOptionId key value, i.e if exist in array and for this I have separate function 'contain(a, obj) which I calling to get Boolean result

this contain function works fine for following test code;

### test code

```
for(var item in questionsList[key].answer)
   {
     var dd = this.contains(questionsList[key].answer, questionsList[key].answer[item].answerValue)
   }
```

but when I do for 'optionSelected' property, it throw error

### component

```
 else  if(questionElementType=="checkbox")
 {

   let _checkBox = new CheckBoxQuestion ({
     consultationId: questionsList[key].consultationId,
     questionId: questionsList[key].questionId,
     questionElementType: questionsList[key].questionElementType[0].title,           
     questionType: questionsList[key].questionType,
     title:questionsList[key].title,
     displayId: questionsList[key].displayId,
     key: questionsList[key].questionId,     
     value: questionsList[key].answer.length<=0? null : questionsList[key].answer[0].answerValue.toLowerCase(),
     label: questionsList[key].title, 
     order: 7,
     options: questionsList[key].answerOptions.map(function(item){                                                
       return {"name": item.ReferenceKey, "key": item.preDefineAnswerOptionId, "value": item.text, "optionSelected": this.contains(questionsList[key].answer, item.preDefineAnswerOptionId)} // need help here, throw error
    }),
   }); 
     this.mappedQuestions.push(_checkBox);
 }
```

### Contain function

```
contains(a, obj)
{

let f:string[]=[];

if(a.length>0)
{
  for(var item in a)
  {
    var answerKey = a[item].answerValue.toLowerCase();

    f.push(answerKey)
  } 

  var i = f.length;
  while (i--) {
     if (f[i] === obj.toLowerCase()) {
         return true;
     }
  }
}

return false;
```

}

### error

```
 error 1-`formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.`
 error 2- Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer,

```
options: questionsList[key].answerOptions.map(function(item){                                                
       return {"name": item.ReferenceKey, "key": item.preDefineAnswerOptionId, "value": item.text, "optionSelected": this.contains(questionsList[key].answer, item.preDefineAnswerOptionId)}
}.bind(this)),
```

Answer (score 0):

**Issue 1:**

Your `form` should be an **instance of form group** so use,  `myForm: FormGroup;`

**Component:**

```
 import {FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

 myForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      title: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
      description: [''],
    });
  }
```

**Html:**

```
 <form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="logForm()">
```

**Issue 2:**

Since you are using normal `function` using `this` inside that will not work.

Use arrow function instead if it is `typescript`

```
 options: questionsList[key].answerOptions.map((item) => {                                                
       return {"name": item.ReferenceKey, "key": item.preDefineAnswerOptionId, "value": item.text, "optionSelected": this.contains(questionsList[key].answer, item.preDefineAnswerOptionId)} // need help here, throw error
    }),
```

Comment: @toxic, what issue you faced in above answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this:

```
function(item) { ... }
```

to use the arrow notation (to hold onto the `this` reference):

```
(item) => { ... }
```

Comment: this answer is same as mine.

Comment: Posted it the same time as you did... happens from time to time.

Comment: I am new to Angular, when I change contain() to function contain(a,obj), i got error --> unexpected token, A constructor method , accessor, or property was expected. ??

Comment: Can you provide more details above on how you are setting the function up? (e.g. is it part of a class or on its own, etc.) This is not enough.

Comment: refer to code under Checkbox class heading, and contain function above in my code

Comment: contain function in component

Comment: I am struggling to apply (item) => { ... } above in my code

Comment: any suggestion?